# Install SharePoint Foundation 2010 - Require system restart

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

- I am heading to install the SharePoint Foundation on my server.
  However, I faced to the problem of requiring the system to restart
  several times. Theses pictures below describe step by step what I
  have done before. Please let me know how to address that issue:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: what happen after the restart?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: It required the system to restart again and again...

Comment: what happen if you try to re run the pre-requisite?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: It just run quickly and show the Installation Complete. However, I still got that error whenever I click on Install SharePoint Foundation.

Comment: did you see any error in Event log, which process is asking for the reboot?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: That is all I've got as you can see on the images.

Comment: Their is one pre-requisite which required reboot, but even after reboot it still not updating it....I think in this case remove all the installed pre-requisite and reboot n trying again.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE: OK. Let me try again. Thank you for your advice. I will feedback soon even it is OK or not.